# Solve linear system of ODEs using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to solve the following initial value problem via Laplace transform
\begin{align*}
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -5 \\ 1 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \mathbf{x} + \begin{pmatrix} \sin t \\ \tan t \end{pmatrix} , \: \mathbf{x}(0) = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to do that since there's no Laplace transform for the tangent function.

Comment: Are u sure about using L.T.?

Comment: Well, the problem appears in the L.T. section of a book on Diferential Equations so I'm assuming there must be a solution using L.T.

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: It's exercise 6 on page 370 in Braun's Differential Equations and Their Applications. You can read it here: http://books.google.com.mx/books?id=USWV3PP3b08C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

There is Laplace transform for tangent function, but it's complicated and using digamma function.
[Laplace transform](http://www.physicsforums.com/showpost.php?s=0a5f20d423639e155a2acb3e9cfdc7f0&p=3448304&postcount=4.%5D%5B1%5D)