# Linear independence of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the general solution $y(x,c_1,c_2)$ of a 2nd-order linear homogeneous ODE, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two parameters and $y$ is assumed to be smooth in $x$, $c_1$, and $c_2$. Take the partial derivatives
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial c_1}(x,c_1,c_2), \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial c_2}(x,c_1,c_2).
$$
Now fix some $(c_1,c_2) = (k_1,k_2)$. Is is true that the functions of $x$ defined by
$$u_1(x) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial c_1}(x,k_1,k_2), \quad u_2(x) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial c_2}(x,k_1,k_2)$$
are linearly independent? If not, what extra assumptions are necessary? Does it depend on the choice of $(k_1,k_2)$, and if so, in what way? The final two questions are extra; I'd really love a proof (even an outline) or counterexample for the first question.

Comment: Are $c_i$ constant like when we write $y_c(x)=C_1y_1+C_2y_2$?? And if so, you are assuming that they are variables?

Comment: They are variable for when we find partial derivatives. Then we fix them to get single-variable functions of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, the partial derivatives are always linearly independent.

The general solution of a second order linear homogeneous ODE $y'' + ay' + by = 0$ is either $y = c_1e^{r_1x} + c_2e^{r_2x}$, if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the two roots of the characteristic polynomial $r^2 + ar + b$, or $y = c_1e^{rx} + c_2xe^{rx}$ if r is a double root of the characteristic polynomial.

In the first case, $\frac {\partial} {\partial c_1}c_1e^{r_1x} + c_2e^{r_2x} = e^{r_1x}$, and $\frac {\partial} {\partial c_2}c_1e^{r_1x} + c_2e^{r_2x} = e^{r_2x}$, which are linearly independent because $r_1$ and $r_2$ are distinct, and in the second case, $\frac{\partial}{\partial c_1} y = c_1e^{rx} + c_2xe^{rx} = e^{rx}$, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial c_2} y = c_1e^{rx} + c_2xe^{rx} = xe^{rx}$, which are again linearly independent.

Note that, since the solutions are linear in $c_1$ and $c_2$, these partial derivatives do not depend on $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Edit: As has been pointed out several times, this only works for constant-coefficient equations. Here is a more general answer:

First we have to notice that any given differential equation won't necessarily have just one "general solution," so the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial y}{\partial c_1}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial c_2}$ won't be well defined (for example, consider the equation $y'' + y = 0$, whose general solution can be written as either $y = c_1cos(x) + c_2sin(x)$ or as $y = c_1e^{ix} + c_2e^{-ix}$). However, for any general solution with a reasonably standard form, the result does hold.

A common form of the general solution of a homogeneous linear second order ODE involves first finding two linearly independent solutions $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, and setting $y(x,c_1,c_2) = c_1\phi_1(x) + c_2\phi_2(x)$. The partial derivatives with respect to $c_1$ and $c_2$ are then $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, which are linearly independent.

Comment: What you noted seems correct but he didn't mention an linear homo. OE **with constant coefficients** :)

Comment: @BabakS.: I don't actually think that this significantly changes the reasoning: to any (nonsingular) second-order linear homogeneous ODE there are two linearly independent solutions ϕ1 and ϕ2, and the general solutions is y=c1ϕ1 + c2ϕ2, so the partials are still ϕ1 and ϕ2, which are, by definition, linearly independent.

Comment: @William: Thanks for your answer but per Babak it's not in the generality I was hoping for. Please outline your reasoning more generally.